# Cannot launch Pydev in Eclipse

Tags: python, java, eclipse

I first installed **Java**; then installed **Eclipse IDE** using [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/) (no problems at all).

Then I installed Pydev using [this](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

But whenever I launch Eclipse in my home folder it opens Java IDE not Python IDE.

---

In **Help --> Installation Details -->** I can find Pydev.

How can I open Python IDE in eclipse or choose the IDE I want?

Python and Java are installed in the same directory.

Comment: Do you have `PyDev` in `Window` > `Preferences`?

Comment: Yes. I can see Pydev in Window --> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to switch to the PyDev perspective instead of the Java perspective. Do this using 'Window > Perspective > Open Perspective' and choose 'Other > PyDev'.